# Link to mylyn task in Java comment (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I have just started using Eclipse and Mylyn together, so I'm quite new to the workflow and how the tools and their features are intended to be used together.

Quite frequently I find myself wanting to write a comment in the code, usually a `// TODO` or similar remark, and reference a ticket in the Trac repository I've hooked myself up to via Mylyn. Currently, I just lookup the ticket number and write something like `// FIXME: bug here, see ticket #18` in the comment.

Is there a way to make that link clickable, so that I can just click in the comment when I find one and it opens the ticket in Mylyn? And vice versa, is there a way to configure Mylyn so that when viewing a ticket I can see all comments referencing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperlinks in comments should be available with the following patterns as long as you have a Trac repository defined in your **Task Repositories** view:

- ticket:128
- #512

You can see the regular expression used [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mylyn.tasks/blob/master/org.eclipse.mylyn.trac.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/trac/ui/TracHyperlinkUtil.java#L40).

You can link a project to a specific Trac repository from the project's **Task Repository** property page available from the *Properties* menu.

Comment: Fantastic! It was the hint about adding a Task Repo to the project I needed to get this working. Now I'm just lacking a way to do the opposite - open a task in MyLyn and see a list of (clickable) comments that reference the task. Is that possible as well?

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible, seeing what comments reference a task from the task editor.