# Link mylyn Jira task to Java source code comment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jira, mylyn

I have pretty much the same question as in the link below except that I'm using the Jira mylyn connector.
I have my Jira Task Repository defined and was just wondering if this is possible.

[Link to mylyn task in Java comment (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720206/link-to-mylyn-task-in-java-comment-eclipse)

i.e. Something like `//See JIRA-123` where the Jira issue number is a clickable link.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct connection between JIRA and Eclipse possible. The reason for that is, that JIRA has no access to your local Eclipse installation. But there is a connection possible e.g. between JIRA and Subversion. So if you use Mylyn, and commit on a JIRA ticket in Mylyn, Mylyn will add automatically the active JIRA ticket ID to the commit message of Subversion. JIRA will then later read the commit message from the Subversion repository (if configured to do that), and will then display a backlink from the ticket to the Subversion Change Set (including diffs).

See the following resources for additional information:

- [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) shows how to link in your Subversion client tool to the JIRA issues.
- [Integration JIRA with Subversion](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Subversion) shows how to link from JIRA to Subversion repository.

You have to have a configuration management system to do that ...

After having read your question again, I think you will need an additional plugin for Mylyn, that interprets your sources and searches there for your JIRA issue ID patterns. But that is a totally different story (and I would not do that ... comments are forgotten, your issues is solved, but the ticket ID remains). Solving a ticket is something that has to do with commits in CM systems.